# og tag link previews dont work consistently in instagram messenger

Tags: angular, instagram, angular-universal

We seem to have a weird problem with og tags in instagram messenger.  Two very similar links from our app - one shows a preview and the other does not.  We have even tried switching the image to be the same and it still does not show up.   Attached below is the snippet of og tags we are using...

```html
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://dev.xxxxxxxx.in/a6731f91f0cba638a063787ab27b07bc7ed2717e0ea0845badcf399ef17916e6?l=1">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="xxxxxxx">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Test title">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Test title description">
    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://xxxxxxx/yyy.png">
```

using the same url in whatsapp shows the preview images.  Has anyone tackled this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Open Graph content was cached. You have to go https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and fill your url.
Then scroll down and check "Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties" section, if there old values, click `Scrape Again` button.

[image]